# Setting up parallel_tests in rake to run rspec tests and ci_reporter

Tags: testing, rspec, parallel-processing, rake

I'm attempting to write a rake file that calls whatever specs I specify with parallel_tests and report the results the using ci_reporter gem.  So something like:

rake parallel_rspec[options] rake-job[options]

I need help setting up parallel_tests in rake properly because the README isn't clear enough for me.

After installing the parallel_tests gem, I can run the following successfully from command line

parallel_rspec spec/location/of/*_spec.rb

When I tried running

rake parallel:test spec

As the README states, it says the task isn't found.  After some googling, added

require 'parallel_tests/tasks'

To the rake file, but then it complained about shellWords being uninitialized.  Then I added

require 'shellWords'

And that problem went away.  However, more issues followed, first in that I couldn't control which specs were executing, and then eventually more errors would show up.

My question, what is the proper way to set up parallel_tests in rake, and secondly, how do I integrate ci_reporter to record the returned results?